# How to use an Enum[]?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, enums

In my project i am using an Array of bool which defines the user's access rights.
For example

```
public bool[] Security {get; set;}
```

where

```
[0] = Admin
[1] = GrantWrites
[2] = GrantDeletes
[3] = User
```

It is working quite well. 
I would set it to {F,T,F,T} or {0,1,0,1} and that particular user gets access as a User and it allows him to write.

I am trying to convert it to an enum but apparently i would need an array of it.

currently i have the following (not working)

```
public class UserCrops
{
    public UserCrops(etc.., Enum[] _Security)
    {
    .
    .
    .
        Security = _Security;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    public Enum[] Security
    {
        Admin,
        GrantWrites,
        GrantDeletes,
        User
    }
```

}

I found some links like [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-array) but no help.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Both answers are very well explained but I am going with the non-Flag one just because it seems easier for me :)

Edit2: How can i create a new object (outside of class?)
I used to do

```
bool[] security = new bool[9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
    security[i] = chklstSecurity.Items[i].Selected;
}
userCropList.Add(new UserCrops(.., txtBiologicalAssessmentApprovalDate.Text, security));
```

But now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `[]` and use `enum` instead of `Enum`:

```
public enum Security
{
    Admin,
    GrantWrites,
    GrantDeletes,
    User
}
```

And you probably want to use `Security[]` as a method parameter:

```
public UserCrops(etc.., Security[] _Security)
```

Using flags (as [*Adriano* suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19806145/1715579)) is an excellent suggestion too, but it will require you to rethink how you're storing your permissions. Instead of storing an array of `bool`'s, you'll represent the entire security set as a single value, with different bits representing each permission.

Read [Enumeration Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) under the section *Enumeration Types as Bit Flags* for more information.

Comment: In this way he cannot set both, for example, GrantWrotes amd GramtDeòetes.

Comment: @Adriano Sure he can using the array, `new[] { Security.GrantWrites, Security.GrantDeletes }`

Comment: yes, I see. I just feel _strange_ to use an array of enums where I may use flags (like an array of 32 bool to represent an Int32 LOL).

Comment: @Adriano Yes both approaches are valid (depending on the exact needs of the application). I intended to mention using flags as well but you beat me to it. +1 :)

Answer (score 7):

Try with:

```
[Flags]
public enum Security
{
    Admin = 1,
    GrantWrites = 2,
    GrantDeletes = 4,
    User = 8
}
```

And you'll use it like this:

```
Security security = Security.GrantWrites | Security.GrantDeletes;

if ((security & Security.GrantWrites) == Security.GrantWrites)
{
}
```

Comparison can be simplified as pointed out by [p.s.w.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806120/how-to-use-an-enum/19806145#comment29446008_19806145) to increase its readability. Moreover I suggest to include a default value in the `enum` (for when variable is not initialized):

```
[Flags]
public enum Security
{
    None = 0,
    Admin = 1,
    GrantWrites = 2,
    GrantDeletes = 4,
    User = 8
}
```

Finally note that you can provider *shortcut* for common combinations of flags:

```
[Flags]
public enum Security
{
    // Other values
    FullAccess = Admin | GrantWrites | GrantDeletes
}
```

More of that on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Please note this approach mimics attributes for file/directories in file system (and many other). IMO is much simpler to use than keep an array of enums as suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19806142/1207195):

- You do not have to search entire array to check if a permission is granted or not.
- You do not have to check for a `null` value (`enum` can't be `null`, an array can be).
- It uses less space (even if nowadays this is not so important).
- It's naturally (more) *safe* so less checks are needed (for example to avoid duplicates inside array).
- It can be easy stored (as text or integer without additional code).

But it has, compared to that, two main drawbacks:

- Flags are finite (32 if you're using an `Int32` for your `enum` or 64 for an `Int64`).
- You can't easily switch to something else (if, for example, `Security` has to become a class you'll need to write *much more* code to mimic enums syntax and some assumption made by code when working with enums will be broken).

Comment: Note `(security & Security.GrantWrites) == Security.GrantWrites` can be simplified to `security.HasFlag(Security.GrantWrites)`. It's also much easier to read.